# beautiful soup wrap between closing and opening tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

new to BeautifulSoup & Python. I want to know if there is way to ad a tag after a closing tag & close it before an opening tag. Or maybe should I modtify my tree? As you can see the p tags are seen as children of title but also a parent.

Here is my sample code:

```
<title> 
  <p> Title Name 1 </p>
</title>
<p> Paragraph 1 </p>
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>
<p> Paragraph 3 </p>
<title> 
  <p> Title Name 2 </p>
</title>
```

Ideal this is what I would want...

```
<title> 
  <p> Title Name 1 </p>
</title>
**<new_tag>**
<p> Paragraph 1 </p>
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>
<p> Paragraph 3 </p>
**</new_tag>**
<title> 
  <p> Title Name 2 </p>
</title>
```

Everytime I try to do soup.find_all('p) or soup.findChildren('p) I do not get the p tag I want or I grab them all so new_tag is added to every p tag. 
It creates the output below. Is there a way to clean up the new_tag and have it look like the ideal output above.

```
<title> 
  <new_tag>
    <p> Title Name 1 </p>
   <new_tag>
</title>
<new_tag>
<p> Paragraph 1 </p>
</new_tag>
<new_tag>
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>
</new_tag>
<new_tag>
<p> Paragraph 3 </p>
</new_tag>
<title> 
<new_tag>
  <p> Title Name 2 </p>
</new_tag>
</title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example in the question, it seems possible to extract all the tags and insert the `'new_tag'` at the appropriate location:

```
p_tags = soup.find_all('p')[1:-1:]
new_tag = soup.new_tag('new_tag')
titles = soup.find_all('title')

titles[0].insert_after(new_tag)

for tag in p_tags:
    new_tag.append(tag)

new_tag.insert_after(titles[1])
```

the result:

```
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<title>
 <p>
  Title Name 1
 </p>
</title>
<new_tag>
 <p>
  Paragraph 1
 </p>
 <p>
  Paragraph 2
 </p>
 <p>
  Paragraph 3
 </p>
</new_tag>
<title>
 <p>
  Title Name 2
 </p>
</title>
```

appears to match the desired result.

Comment: Thank you ! This helps I am still getting empty <new_tag>, However those can be cleaned up easily: <new_tag>
</new_tag>
<new_tag>
</new_tag>
<new_tag>
</new_tag>